# What is the difference between these two snippets of c++ code

Tags: c++, if-statement, max, min, intersection

These are my answers for a *codeforces* problem and I don't know why the first snippet gives a wrong answer.

The second is accepted though.

I want to know if there is a problem with the judgment test cases because they seem to give the same output.

The problem says the following:

> Given the boundaries of 2 intervals. Print the boundaries of their intersection.

> Note: Boundaries mean the two ends of an interval which are the starting number and the ending number.

> **Input**:
> Only one line contains two intervals [l1,r1], [l2,r2] where (1≤l1,l2,r1,r2≤109), (l1≤r1,l2≤r2).

> It's guaranteed that l1≤r1 and l2≤r2.

> **Output**:
> If there is an intersection between these 2 intervals print its boundaries , otherwise print -1.

Snippet 1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    int z;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    if(a > b)
    {
        z = a;
        a = b;
        b = z;
    }
    if(c > d)
    {
        z = c;
        c = d;
        d = z;
    }
    if(c > b)
    {
        cout << -1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << max(a, c) << " " << min(b, d);
    }
    return 0
}
```

Snippet 2

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int l1 , r1 , l2 , r2;
    cin >> l1 >> r1 >> l2 >> r2;
    int _begin = max(l1,l2);
    int _end = min(r1,r2);
    if (_begin > _end)
        cout << -1;
    else
        cout << begin << " " << end;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at your variables and compare how the second snippet uses its variables. There is a very noticeable difference there

Comment: Snippet 1's first two `if`s will never be true. The input is stated to have a guarantee that `l1 <= r1` and `l2 <= r2`. Those twelve lines don't actually do anything.

Comment: Don't be "That Guy". Give your variables meaningful names. It makes the code easier to read and it makes it easier for the compiler to catch trivial typos. It's amazing how hard it is to spot a transposition of `b` and `d` in code.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Don't do this.  Include the proper headers, in this case `#include <iostream>` and `#include <algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first program you are checking only one condition

```
if(c > b)
{
    cout << -1;
}
```

But you need to check also the following condition

```
if ( d < a )
{
    cout << -1;
}
```

For example

```
if(c > b || d < a )
{
    cout << -1;
}
else
{
    //...
}
```